# Store json response to object so can get the value from the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying the get the geonames' API which will response JSON data.
I create a dataStorage Object and put the response in it.
Currently I have problem when getting the value from the storing object.

Here is my code:

```js
var dataStorage = new Object();

function CountryQuery(geoId, geoCode) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=" + geoId + "&username=tompi",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      dataStorage[geoCode] = data;
    }
  });
}

if (!('AN' in dataStorage)) {
  CountryQuery(6255152, "AN");
}

$(dataStorage).find('AN').geonames.countryName;
```

The JSON response is look like below:

```
{  
   "totalResultsCount":2,
   "geonames":[  
      {  
         "countryId":"6697173",
         "countryCode":"AQ",
         "name":"Antarctica",
         "countryName":"Antarctica"
      },
      {  
         "countryId":"3371123",
         "countryCode":"BV",
         "name":"Bouvet Island",
         "countryName":"Bouvet Island"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSON snippet? Can't access it right now, would like to look at that first.

Comment: you are initializing `datastorage` in the wrong way.. also it would be helpful if you provide a sample of the expected JSON

Comment: @mplungjan Maybe datastorage is global somewhere and he wants to add the response in a key called `geoCode`..  that way he could possibly use the IN where he is using it..not very clear though..

Comment: True..That's why this question needs more clarification..

Comment: Sorry for the wrong typing method. should be "find()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
dataStorage.push(geoCode,data);
```

instead of:

```
dataStorage[geoCode] = data;
```

and if you are looking for 'AN' as country code then your query will further not work..You will have to iterate through the JSON and check for the values.. `in` only checks the keys..

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am able to get the data from using 
"dataStorage["AN"].geonames[0].countryName"

Answer (score -2):

Your main issue is that the ajax request is *asynchronous*. This means that the function `CountryQuery` returns immediately, before the request returns the JSON value. You have to get the value from `dataStorage` inside the success function:

```
var dataStorage = {};

function countryQuery(geoId, geoCode, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://api.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=' + geoId + '&username=tompi',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            dataStorage[geoCode] = data;
            callback();
        }
    });
}

function useDataStorage() {
  alert(dataStorage.AN.geonames[0].countryName);
}

if (dataStorage.AN === undefined) countryQuery('6255152', 'AN', useDataStorage);
else useDataStorage();
```